# Как все-таки правильнее?

Tags: фразеология, прописная-строчная, кавычки, междометие

В учебниках по русскому пишут *эге-ге*, но в интернете говорится, что надо *э-ге-ге*. Как правильнее?

А еще мне говорили, что *ни что иное* — это устойчивое сочетание и пишется с частицей **НИ**, но в интернете говорят, что верно — *не что иное*. Как вернее?

Кстати, правильно ли я написал «частица **НИ**», заглавными буквами и полужирным шрифтом? Или нужны кавычки и строчные буквы?

Comment: Лесков писал так: Глава первая — Э, ге-ге-ге! Нет, уж ты, батюшка мой, со мною, сделай милость, не спорь!

Comment: Э-ге-ге - это когда кричат, о-го-го, э-ге-ге. Скорее всего производные от геть - вон его, прогнать вон. А эге-ге - это междометие выражающее замешательство ~ вот те на, вот это да. Э-ге-ге - подгонять, разгонять кого-то. А эге-ге - посмотри мол. "Эге-ге, брат, как мы с тобой постарели!" - Тургенев. "Кирюха кашлял, смеялся и кричал так, как будто его хотели утопить, а Дымов гонялся за ним и старался схватить его за ногу. — Ге-ге-ге! — кричал он. — Лови, держи его!" - Булгаков. или он же: [Ракеев (муж)] "Э-ге-ге... Арестовать!"

Comment: «Э-ге-ге! вот оно что!» — сказывал этот свист. Э-ге-ге - больше экспрессии и указание: вот он, держи его! А эге-ге - это более спокойное, мол подумай, что делать.

Comment: "Не что иное, как" подавляющее число употребление, "ни что иное, как" - редкость 2000+к~130. Так что скорее всего, вы не так запомнили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**О кодификации как она есть**

Ответ следует дополнить сведениями из других источников, **не менее важных** для кодификации, чем орфографический словарь.

1. Орфографический словарь: ***эге***, неизм.
2. Большой толковый словарь: ***ЭГЕ; Э-ГЕ-ГЕ***, межд. Употр. при обнаружении чего-л. **значительного, любопытного или неожиданного**; вот оно что, вот как. Эге, вот ты где! Э-ге-ге, нашёл!
3. [ПАС под ред. Лопатина: § 141.](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=74)

Пишутся через дефис следующие служебные слова и междометия. **Пункт 4. Междометия** (включая звукоподражания): бай-бай, баю-бай, баюшки-баю, ей-богу, ей-ей, ей-же-ей, ку-ку, тю-тю, ну-ка, ну-тка, о-го-го, о-хо-хо, пиф-паф, тик-так, тра-та-та, ля-ля-ля, ха-ха, хе-хе, хи-хи, цып-цып, чик-чирик, ***э-ге-ге, э-хе-хе.***

**Размышления на тему**

Конечно, всегда можно **найти ответ** в словаре — что же проще. Но давайте вспомним, что у нас не только сайт вопросов-ответов, как другие, но и **форум лингвистов и энтузиастов русской словесности.**  В данной теме обе крайности нежелательны — как произвольное письмо, так и желание всегда следовать правилам  без должного их **понимания**.

**Обратимся** к русской словесности. В Нацорпусе встречаются разные формы письма: ***эге-ге*** — [74 примера](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CmsiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCGAoWChQKA3JlcRINCgvRjdCz0LUt0LPQtTAA), ***э-ге-ге*** — [13 примеров](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CmwiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCGQoXChUKA3JlcRIOCgzRjS3Qs9C1LdCz0LUwAA==). Этот факт желательно учесть, а не считать, что наши известные писатели и мыслители  заблуждаются и принятой кодификации следовать не хотят.

**Попробуем сравнить две формы письма**. Существуют междометия ***эге*** и ***э-ге-ге*** с одинаковым толкованием в словаре. Но в каких ситуациях  они применимы?  Вот вы обнаружили нечто **значительное, любопытное или неожиданное.** А какую фразу вы при этом произнесёте, ведь смысловые оттенки могут быть разными? Здесь следует приветствовать желание нашего участника @Буратино  **найти этот смысл**, прислушаться  к слову.

С другой стороны, форма ***эге-ге*** повторяет междометие ***эге***, такое деление на две части мы слышим в речи, и оно представляется закономерным.  В то же время деление на три части тоже возможно в определенных случаях. Тогда, может, следует узаконить **обе формы письма** (э-ге-ге и эге-ге)? Почему же была выбрана одна и **признана лучшей**? И объективно ли это?

Поэтому применять правила нужно **осознанно**, а не просто принимать к сведению и **беспрекословно «слушаться».** Да, в учебных примерах надо писать ***э-ге-ге*** по правилам, но писатель имеет право выбрать нужную форму. Ну мне так думается, а как думаете вы?

**Статья о кодификации**

В интернете можно много чего найти, в том числе и полезную информацию.
Интересная статья  И. В. Нечаева **ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКАЯ КОДИФИКАЦИЯ СЕГОДНЯ И КОЛЛЕГИАЛЬНОСТЬ НОРМАТИВНЫХ РЕШЕНИЙ**
https://ruslang.ru/doc/nechaeva2012a.pdf

*Научное обоснование нормативного выбора – потребность времени. Как пишет В. Г. Костомаров, «чтобы люди **слушались Свода**..., он должен стать из приказного, командно-императивного объяснительным, ориентирующим и не чуждаться объективно возникающих новшеств, вообще меняющегося вкуса» [Костомаров 1999: 281]. Добавим, что это должно касаться не только правил, но и **словарной нормы.** До сих пор считалось необходимым обнародовать лишь **результат** кодификации. Однако читателя волнует вопрос, не только **КАК** должно писаться слово, но и **ПОЧЕМУ** оно должно писаться так, а не иначе.*

*Проблема в том, что ответить на этот вопрос порой не могут **и сами кодификаторы**. Поэтому в центр научного внимания должно быть помещено не определение частных, пословных орфограмм, а разработка  **о б щ и х принципов** правописания применительно **к целым категориям слов**. Системное выявление факторов, которые влияют на написание слова, а также определение критериев, которые используются при кодификации – в целом не решенная на сегодняшний день задача теории нормирования.*

Comment: Эге-ге - это от эге с растягиванием/повтором слога. А э-ге-ге - это или от э-хе-хе (смех) или от геть - взять его, либо э-ге-ге - может значить нет, нельзя. Вообще Э - это такое словечко, замешательства, размышления. Есть еще мычание м-мм. Эти м-мм и э-ээ - такие словечки которые произносят не только у нас, это даже не междометия бывают, а какое-то заполнение пауз в речи, связки мысли и речи.

Comment: Человек сам говорит что-то и экает мыкает. вот пример, китаец говорит и экает), ну ему сложно говорить переводя мысли на русский язык, в целом понятно, но у него набор этих эканий-ыканий-оканий специфический, очень забавный, но именно характерный для разговорной речи и это прямо отдельные какие-то междометья, полувербальная речь какая-то: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tx6eXlgFwA

Answer (score 2):

Кодифицированные написания (см. «**Русский орфографический словарь**»:

**[э-ге-ге](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%8D-%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B5)**,

**[ничто иное](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5&all=x)** (ничто иное его не интересует),

**[не что иное, как…](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)**

Comment: Что такое "кодифицированные написания"?

Comment: КОДИФИЦИРОВАННЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Лингв. Нормированный, образцовый.  http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x

Comment: Тогда не понятно, э-ге-ге - это кодирование чего? даже значения нет в словаре Лопатина. Или для кодифицирования достаточно указать часть речи?

Comment: Кодифицирование – указание в словаре орфографически верного написания.

Comment: Прекрасно, на основании чего? Что именно правильно писать?

Comment: @oleedd ну и смысл в чём? То что что-то там кодифицировали я понял, а что именно? То есть я напишу в словаре слово: олфыдал - междометие. И что? Что это такое?

Comment: @Буратино Вариант написания. Ага, это от слова "кодекс", а не "код", то есть добавили в кодекс (правила, словари).

Comment: @oleedd кодекс и код - однокоренные. Кодекс - список кодов. Что кодируют-то? Ну есть междометие э-ге-ге, все, хорошо, а междометие эге-ге - не закодировано, значит вне правил? При том, что даже не ясно, что конкретно кодировали в э-ге-ге.

Comment: @Буратино Но кажется, что напрямую от "код". По идее, должно быть "кодексифицировать". Кодифицируют один вариант написания, который считают лучшим (объективно), то есть наиболее правильным, чтобы не было разнобоя.

Answer (score 0):

**Из ответа Sharon в этой теме:**

> …Форма ***эге-ге*** повторяет междометие эге, такое деление на две
> части мы слышим в речи, и оно представляется закономерным. В то же
> время деление на три части тоже возможно в определенных случаях.
> Тогда, может, следует узаконить **обе формы письма** (э-ге-ге и
> эге-ге)?

**«Форма** ***эге-ге*** **повторяет междометие** ***эге***…»

???

**По-моему, совсем не повторяет.** Междометие ***эге*** произносится с ударением на втором слоге - и, хотя бы лично у меня, при полном выдохе. Произнеся это ***эгЕ***, я не могу дополнительно к нему произнести ***ге*** так, как оно произносится  в ***«э/ге/гЕ»***, имеющем **основное ударение не на втором, а на третьем слоге**.

**«В то же время деление на три части тоже возможно в определенных случаях…»**

???

**Как случаи с «эге-ге» и «э-ге-ге» можно различить на слух?** И какими такими «смысловыми оттенками» они отличаются друг от друга? По-моему, никакими. И потому совершенно не понимаю Вашего предложения «узаконить **обе формы письма** (э-ге-ге и эге-ге)». Напомню, что произносятся это «эгегЕ» будет абсолютно одинаково, сколько бы дефисов мы в нём ни поставили. Кстати, у некоторых авторов *эгеге* именно так и писалось – вообще без дефисов…

Ну а ж какую форму стоило узаконить – это другой вопрос. На сегодняшний день *узаконена* одна: ***э-ге-ге***.

…

**Из комментариев **Буратино** к этому ответу:**

> **э-ге-ге**, э-хе-хе - подражание смеху. А **эге-ге** – это не смех.

По-моему, примеры из Нацкорпуса не подтверждают такое толкование. Писатели использовали и ***эге-ге*** при подражаниях смеху, и ***э-ге-ге*** – в совсем не смешных ситуациях.

См.:

*— ***Эге-ге!*** — засмеялся Платоша…*

***Эге-ге**, пане Иване, — не выдержал, рассмеялся он весело…*

```
                                                                                ***Э-ге-ге**… Арестовать!*
```

Comment: э-ге-ге, э-хе-хе - подражание смеху. А эге-ге - это не смех. Произносить можно по-разному и с разной интонацией, не думаю, что междометью можно вообще установить какую-то норму произнесения.

Comment: @Буратино, попросите кого-нибудь из своих знакомых  произнести эти «эге-ге» и «э-ге-ге» и попробуйте найти разницу в их произношении.

Comment: Причем тут знакомые, я вам говорю, что я могу произнести для себя с вот такой вот разницей и вижу что писатели тоже писали по-разному, значит у них на то были причины, у меня прямо сейчас под рукой нет знакомых искушенных в языке, языком. Я сам могу произнести по-разному, потому и пишу об этом. И если вы советуете, начните с себя, найдите человек 10 и попросите(можно в письменно, чтобы не провоцировать интонацию) их по-разному произнести эге-ге и э-ге-ге и объяснить разницу в произнесении, если такая имеется. Потом расскажете, что получилось и обсудим.

Comment: Наши литераторы  (еще до кодификации) записывали  междометие по слуху. Произношение уж точно может быть разным (по длительности звука, по паузам), здесь нужно особый слух и  умение, чтобы его записать и уловить оттенки смысла. Школьники пусть пишут "э-ге-ге" по кодификации в базовом варианте, но в литературных текстах частотность явно не в пользу кодифицированного  "э-ге-ге".

Comment: Не могу понять, почему последний пример, который есть в моём ответе, не виден. Может, превышена допустимая длина ответа?

Comment: Эге-ге - употреблений на нацкорпусе подавляющее большинство. Не могу ничего сказать, по части того, откуда вы взяли эти фразы. Хотя про платошу, это Первухин, который явно не писатель, а политик, может вообще не он текст писал, а негры. А вот Тургенев: «Эге, ге!.. — подумал про себя Аркадий. И кому доверять? У кого чувство языка точнее?

Comment: Насчет э-ге-ге... Арестовать! - сарказм, тоже насмешка, почему нет. Я доверяю немного себе и авторитетным писателям: Лескову, Тургеневу, Пушкину, Достоевскому ... может еще кому, а в остальном нужно смотреть, кто писал. вы вот не озаботились, чтобы уточнить, кто именно писал фразы и у вас получился просто "писатели пишут". Мало ли кто пишет, писатели разные бывают, я тоже, может, писатель, просто неизвестный)

Comment: @Буратино: _вы вот не озаботились, чтобы уточнить, кто именно писал фразы и у вас получился просто "писатели пишут"._ === Я вынужден был выкинуть ссылки на авторов фраз, пытаясь сохранить последний пример. Но и это мне не помогло…

Comment: @Слава ясно. я там тоже напутал, Первухин, скорее всего это прозаик и журналист, родился в Харькове, потому и паны далее... Ну да ладно, суть в чем, что вот он писал вот так, а Тургенев не так, а Булгаков еще как то и арестовать, и последний вкладывал интонацию? В этом сложность. А однозначно сказать сложно, нужно смотреть по тексту и все равно, скорее всего, зависит от читателя, какая интонация будет: насмешка или серьёзно... Я почему так заморачиваюсь, потому что ладно у междометий, но у даже казалось бы понятных и известных слов, может быть совсем другое звучание.

Comment: Благо нацкорпус позволяет увидеть разницу вне кодификации кодификаторов, живой русский увидеть и прочитать. А не вот вам код - пишите так, даже без указания, а что собственно писать, то есть даже без толкования.